# deserialize json from Moodle web service with Jackson (java)

Tags: java, json, jackson

I need to parse a JSON object obtained from a call to the Moodle REST api. The JSON response I get is:

```
{"users":[{"id":2,"username":"admin","firstname":"Amministratore","lastname":"Utente","fullname":"Amministratore Utente","email":"email@address.com","department":"","firstaccess":1475831148,"lastaccess":1477493148,"description":"","descriptionformat":1,"profileimageurlsmall":"http:\/\/vmoodle.local\/theme\/image.php\/clean\/core\/1475846316\/u\/f2","profileimageurl":"http:\/\/vmoodle.local\/theme\/image.php\/clean\/core\/1475846316\/u\/f1","preferences":[{"name":"auth_manual_passwordupdatetime","value":"1475831184"},{"name":"email_bounce_count","value":"1"},{"name":"email_send_count","value":"1"},{"name":"_lastloaded","value":1477561370}]}],"warnings":[]}
```

I'd like to map this json to a POJO, so I wrote two classes:

```
public class MoodleUser {

        public MoodleUser() {
        }

        private int id;
        private String username;

        /**
         * @return the id
         */
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        /**
         * @param id the id to set
         */
        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        /**
         * @return the username
         */
        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }

        /**
         * @param username the username to set
         */
        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }

    }

    public class MoodleUsers {

        public MoodleUsers() {

        }

        private List<MoodleUser> users;

        /**
         * @return the users
         */
        public List<MoodleUser> getUsers() {
            return users;
        }

        /**
         * @param users the users to set
         */
        public void setUsers(List<MoodleUser> users) {
            this.users = users;
        }

    }
```

And then I call:

```
MoodleUsers response = oMapper.readValue(result, MoodleUsers.class);
```

What I get is an Exception reporting the following error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of mypackage.lms.MoodleClientRest$MoodleUsers: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: {"users":[{"id":12,"username":"userok","firstname":"Nome test","lastname":"Cognome test","fullname":"Nome test Cognome test","email":"email@test.it","department":"","idnumber":"cftest","firstaccess":0,"lastaccess":0,"description":"","descriptionformat":1,"country":"IT","profileimageurlsmall":"http:\/\/vmoodle.local\/theme\/image.php\/clean\/core\/1475846316\/u\/f2","profileimageurl":"http:\/\/vmoodle.local\/theme\/image.php\/clean\/core\/1475846316\/u\/f1"}],"warnings":[]}
; line: 1, column: 2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:261)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.instantiationException(DeserializationContext.java:1456)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1012)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1203)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:314)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:148)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3789)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2833)
```

I already have the default constructors in my pojo's, so I can't understand where the problem resides. Any suggestions?
Thank you.

Comment: How have you configured your `ObjectMapper`? Do you have this feature disabled: `objectMapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);`?

Comment: Just a thought: your class `MoodleUser` does not show the same members as you get from the JSON. for example the Json states that there is a String `firstname`, but your `MoodleUser` doesn't have that field. So either you add these fields or you try annotating your class to tell Jackson what to de-/serialize and what not to [Examples for Annotations](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations)

Comment: @Robby that configuration is for old Jackson versions. For Jackson 2.0 it's `oMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);`. Thank you for the hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the class in the excpetion: `mypackage.lms.MoodleClientRest$MoodleUsers` suggests that `MoodleUsers` is an inner class of `MoodleClientRest` and in that case it **has** to be public static in order for jackson to successfully instantiate objects.

Comment: this was the problem. When declaring the classes as stand-alone classes, anyway, I get another exception due to the fact that my pojo's do not define all the attributes in the json:

`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "firstname" (class mypackage.lms.MoodleUser), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "id", "username"])`

I'll check the suggestions in the other comments to try solving that.